# How to extract multiple image from SQL database with one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2014, procedure

I tried following query for export images to selective folder but it export only one file in one time but I want all image export at same time.

```
USE [DanfeyPhoto]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_ExportImage]    Script Date: 7/31/2021 7:36:40 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
----- first ma database lai sql 2014 ma restore gareko xa vane matra yo query le kam garxa.
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ExportImage] (
   @PicName NVARCHAR (100)
   ,@ImageFolderPath NVARCHAR(1000)
   ,@Filename NVARCHAR(1000)
   )
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ImageData VARBINARY (max);
   DECLARE @Path2OutFile NVARCHAR (2000);
   DECLARE @Obj INT
   set @ImageFolderPath='D:\PhotoExtract\'

   SET NOCOUNT ON
 
   SELECT @ImageData = (
         SELECT convert (VARBINARY (max), photoim, 1)
         FROM MemberDetail
         WHERE MemberNo = @PicName
         );
 
   SET @Path2OutFile = CONCAT (
         @ImageFolderPath
         ,'\'
         , @Filename
         );
    BEGIN TRY
     EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream' ,@Obj OUTPUT;
     EXEC sp_OASetProperty @Obj ,'Type',1;
     EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Open';
     EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Write', NULL, @ImageData;
     EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'SaveToFile', NULL, @Path2OutFile, 2;
     EXEC sp_OAMethod @Obj,'Close';
     EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj;
    END TRY
    
 BEGIN CATCH
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj;
 END CATCH
 
   SET NOCOUNT OFF
END

-- EXEC [dbo].[usp_ExportImage] '00001', 'D:\PhotoExtract', '00001.jpg'
-- select * from MemberDetail
```

Comment: You can use a cursor.

Comment: Or a `while` loop - but to be clear you really shouldn't be doing this in your database. Write a small PowerShell script or something.

Comment: Absolutely you should avoid `sp_OA` procedures like the plague. Do this in POwershell, C# or Python, anything, just not T-SQL, it's not the place for it